# static_assert in templated member function of non-template class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I finally switched to MSVC 2022 in the last couple days and am getting a static_assert from code that had previously been working fine.

I have a type that needs to have a member implemented differently based on whether a template parameter type is trivally constructable and destructable or not, but have not yet actually implemented any of that logic. I've been using static_assert(false, "not yet implemented") as a guard against accidental use of the member.

I've pared it down to the following example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class TestClass
{
    size_t MemberFn() { /* shared stuff between trivial and non-trivial */
        return 0;
    }
    template<typename Type>
    size_t MemberFn(std::enable_if_t<!std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Type> || !std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Type>>* = nullptr)
    {
        static_assert(false, "not implemented yet");
        return 0;
    }
    template<typename Type>
    size_t MemberFn(std::enable_if_t<std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Type> && std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Type>>* = nullptr)
    {
        static_assert(false, "not implemented yet");
        return 0;
    }
};
```

When I try building this I get the following (and similar for the second member template):

```
2>D:\projects\TestLib\TestLib\testlib.h(18,17): error C2338: static_assert failed: 'not implemented yet'
2>D:\projects\TestLib\TestLib\testlib.h(16,9): message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'size_t TestClass::MemberFn(enable_if<!std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Type,>||!std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Type>,void>::type *)'
```

Note that I do not actually have a call to this function anywhere, and the diagnostic does not tell me what actual type the compiler is trying to use. Basically I wish to go back to this particular function being ignored as it did with MSVC 2019.

I am compiling with /std:c++latest and /permissive- and would prefer to keep those.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your compiler has not implemented a solution for [DR2518](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2518.html) which states that

- If the value of the expression when so converted is `true` **or the expression is evaluated in the context of a template definition**, the declaration has no effect. Otherwise, the `static_assert`-declaration fails

Since you have `static_assert(false, "...");` in a template definition that is uninstantiated, it should not be refused by the compiler.

Implementations which haven't implemented a solution for the above defect report still abide by the old rules, shown in the old part of this answer:

---

[[`dcl.pre`]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#10)

> In a `static_assert`-declaration, the constant-expression is contextually converted to `bool` and the converted expression shall be a constant expression (`[expr.const]`). If the value of the expression when so converted is `true`, the declaration has no effect. **Otherwise, the program is ill-formed**, and the resulting diagnostic message (`[intro.compliance]`) should include the text of the string-literal, if one is supplied.

By putting `false` in your `static_assert` you've made the program ill-formed and the compiler is correct when rejecting the program.

---

A possible workaround could be to make the assertion dependent on the template parameter, at least superficially.

```cpp
template<class>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool always_false_v = always_false<T>::value;

class TestClass {
    size_t MemberFn() { /* shared stuff between trivial and non-trivial */
        return 0;
    }
    template <typename Type>
    size_t MemberFn(
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Type> ||
                         !std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Type>>* = nullptr) {
        static_assert(always_false_v<Type>, "not implemented yet");
        return 0;
    }
    template <typename Type>
    size_t MemberFn(
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Type> &&
                         std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Type>>* = nullptr) {
        static_assert(always_false_v<Type>, "not implemented yet");
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the thrust of the question. It seems they have a function template which, if not specialized, should resolve to the default implementation that static-asserts and fails to compile. In their previous compiler, it would not evaluate the `static_assert` when parsing the header -- only if actually resolving the template. In the newer compiler, they are seeing the `static_assert` always being evaluated despite the template not being used. If you have actually answered this, then please clarify how this specification translates to the behavior they see.

Comment: @paddy It's still parsed even though not used. If one wants to make it depend on instantiations, one could add a `bool Implemented = false` template parameter to the functions. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/57Ga3qY8o). The `static_assert` is then made dependent on the value of the template parameter and won't kick in until actually used.

Comment: Okay, this would seem to be an example of MSVC 2019 just not following the language spec. I changed ./permissive- to /permissive and this error goes away. Guess I'll just use a run-time check to guard against actually using these for now.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yes, it was most probably MSVC2019 that had some loophole there. Instead of runtime checks, you could make it dependent like I showed in the example in my previous comment.

Comment: @TedLyngmo FYI, you don't need the `always_false` template, the `always_false_v` template can be simplified to: `template<class>
inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;` The `always_false_v` template itself doesn't need to use the template argument, what is important is that the `static_assert` uses a template argument when instantiating `always_false_v`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, but I'm in automatic mode when I make traits so I'll always make one that works without template variables too. Just in case someone uses C++11. Old habit and not even needed for VS2022 that doesn't even have C++11 :)

Answer (score 1):

Raymond Chen covered this issue in his blog:

[How can I create a type-dependent expression that is always false?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553)

> ```
> auto lambda = [total](auto op, auto value) mutable
> {
>   ...
>   static_assert(false, "Don't know what you are asking me to do.");
>   ...
> };
> ```
>
> However, this does not compile because the `static_assert` fails immediately.
>
> The reason is that the controlling expression for the `static_assert` is not dependent upon the type of the arguments, and therefore **it is evaluated when the lambda is compiled, not when the lambda is invoked** (and the implicit template instantiated).
>
> In order to defer the `static_assert` to instantiation, **we need to make it type-dependent**.

[Of what use is a type-dependent expression that is always false?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200312-00/?p=103556)

> Last time, we saw how to create a type-dependent expression that is always false, and used it in a potentially-discarded statement so that the assertion failed only if the statement ended up being used.
>
> **Another case where you want to defer a static assertion failure to instantiation is if you want to reject a particular specialization.**

So, you need to make the `static_assert` condition be dependent on the template argument. Raymond showed two ways to do that:

Using a custom helper template:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename>
inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;

class TestClass
{
    ...

    template<typename Type>
    size_t MemberFn(std::enable_if_t<!std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Type> || !std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Type>>* = nullptr)
    {
        static_assert(always_false_v<Type>, "not implemented yet");
        return 0;
    }

    template<typename Type>
    size_t MemberFn(std::enable_if_t<std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Type> && std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Type>>* = nullptr)
    {
        static_assert(always_false_v<Type>, "not implemented yet");
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Using `sizeof()`:

```
#include <type_traits>

class TestClass
{
    ...

    template<typename Type>
    size_t MemberFn(std::enable_if_t<!std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Type> || !std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Type>>* = nullptr)
    {
        static_assert(!sizeof(Type*), "not implemented yet");
        return 0;
    }

    template<typename Type>
    size_t MemberFn(std::enable_if_t<std::is_trivially_constructible_v<Type> && std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Type>>* = nullptr)
    {
        static_assert(!sizeof(Type*), "not implemented yet");
        return 0;
    }
};
```